# Dealing with VB.NET Linq formatting in Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, visual-studio-2010

Does anyone else wrestle with getting VB.NET Linq code formatted the way they want it in Visual Studio?  What are some tricks you have for how do you deal with it?  I know that Visual Studio lets you uncheck the option for "Pretty listing (reformatting) of code", but most of the time it's a really handy setting to keep on.  And with a team of developers who could have other settings, that's not really a viable solution.  So my questions are:

1. How have you dealt with formatting multiline Linq statements in VB without fighting with Visual Studio's code formatting?
2. Is there a particular style guide for Linq in VB.NET that is recommended?  Something that is readable, and that Visual Studio likes without the reformatting nightmares?

---

***Edit -***

My original question may not have had the clarity I desired.  Here's a more concrete example.  Take this fake linq query:

```
Dim query = From a In dc.GetTable(Of DAL.GenericTableDao)()
            Select New With {
              .ID = a.ID,
              .SomethingElse = a.SomethingElse,
              .MyOtherRecord = (
                  From dtl In dc.GetTable(Of DAL.DetailTableDao)()
                  Where dtl.ID2 = a.ID _
                  AndAlso dtl.Code = a.Code _
                  Select dtl.RecordName
              ).FirstOrDefault(),
              .LastField = a.LastField
            }
```

Everything is all nicely formatted and lined up, but any changes to the query result in Visual Studio borking the formatting and only an immediate CTRL-Z will stop it.  Which is fine if there's a standard way that VS would like to see multiline Linq formatted, but if not, then the constant reformatting VS tries makes no sense.  I'm trying to see if I missed some standard or how others in the community deal with this effectively.  (BTW - using tabs instead of spaces for indents.  Not sure if that plays into this problem or not.)

---

***Edit 2 -***

Solved it.  See answer below.

Comment: Can you post an example of what bad formatting looks like vs what you think would look better?

Comment: It's not me that's making a judgment on formatting as much as Visual Studio.  I don't care what the formatting looks like, I just don't want VS de-denting my multiline linq any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it.  I have `Smart` indenting turned on for VB.  Tabs are fine, pretty listing of code is fine, but indents have to be set to `Block` in order for Visual Studio to leave well enough alone.  Thanks to @rockinthesixstring and @rossisdead for [rubber-ducking](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?RubberDucking) me through it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a definitive guide, but I definitely have a preference.  I prefer to put a break after everything.

Here's a lambda expression I use in my service layer

```
        Return _RegionRepository.GetRegions() _
            .Where(Function(r) (r.Region = region _
                                And r.ParentID = parentid _
                                And r.isActive)) _
            .FirstOrDefault()
```

Notice the underscore after every query item

Here's an update method that I use

```
        Dim _user = (From u In dc.Users
            Where u.ID = user.ID
            Select u).Single

        With _user
            .About = user.About
            .BirthDate = user.BirthDate
            .Email = user.Email
            .isClosed = user.isClosed
            .isProfileComplete = user.isProfileComplete
            .RegionID = user.RegionID
            .ParentRegionID = user.ParentRegionID
            .Reputation = user.Reputation
            .UserName = user.UserName
            .WebSite = user.WebSite
        End With

        dc.SubmitChanges()
```

Basically I like everything nice and clean and to have every "thought" on it's own line.

Comment: That makes sense, but I think you misunderstood my question.  Let's take your first code sample.  You've got it formatted all nice and pretty.  Try inserting another `And` (aside: always use `AndAlso`!!!) in your Linq query.  VS will de-dent your lovely alignment.  Then, add another blank line underneath your query and VS will change your indent again!  My question is how to keep VS happy.